# Call to a member function on null by inject extended Repository

Tags: typo3

In my extension "MyExt" I extend the controller of extension "ExtA". In this controller I want to load an extended version of the NewsRepository, but I always get a

```
Call to a member function getMyNews() on null
```

My Controller-Code looks like this:

```
<?php
  namespace M3\MyExt\Controller;

  use VendorA\ExtA\Domain\Model\ModelA;
  use M3\MyExt\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository;


  /**
   * Class ModelAController
   * @package M3\MyExt\Controller
   */
  class ModelAController extends \VendorA\ExtA\Controller\ModelAController
  {
      /**
       * @var NewsRepository|null
       */
      private ?NewsRepository $newsRepository = null;

      /**
       * @param NewsRepository $newsRepository
       * @return void
       */
      public function injectNewsRepository(NewsRepository $newsRepository)
      {
          $this->newsRepository = $newsRepository;
      }


      public function Action()
      {
          ...
          $news = $this->newsRepository->getMyNews();
          ...
      }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

At least phpstorm doesn't complain...

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use? If v11, check the Dependency Injection settings.

Comment: Your injections look fine. Did you rebuild the php autoload information in the maintenance section?

Comment: extending news is a bit different than common cases, you can have a look here how the repositories are acquired: https://github.com/georgringer/eventnews/blob/main/Classes/Controller/NewsController.php#L38-L47

Comment: beside that, it might be possible that your code is working too, but only after the cache is warmed up either by distinct possibilities for this or just by calling the pages twice while the first time it fails. It's about the new-cache where you should be able to discover your code in the news-controller. It's resided in `var/cache/code/news`

Comment: I am using TYPO3 10.
Using `$this->objectManager->get` I can call my extended NewsRepository:

`$newsRepository = $this->objectManager->get(\M3\MyExt\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository::class);
$news = $newsRepository->getMyNews($addressUid);`

But I get ther error `Table 'database.tx_myext_domain_model_news' doesn't exist`

Comment: In my NewsRepository I extend the GeorgRinger NewsRepository:
`class NewsRepository extends \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository`

Comment: Have a look at ext_localconf.php found in https://github.com/georgringer/eventnews/blob/main/ext_localconf.php in part
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['classes']['Domain/Model/News'][] = 'eventnews';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['classes']['Controller/NewsController'][] = 'eventnews';

Comment: I add `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['classes']['Domain/Repository/NewsRepository'][] = 'myext';`in ext_localconf.php but get always the error `'database.tx_myext_domain_model_news' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this seems to work:

In my Controller Action:

```
...
$newsRepository = $this->objectManager->get(\MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository::class);
$news = $newsRepository->getMyNews();
...
```

And in `EXT:myext/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
return [
   \M3\Wihemer\Domain\Model\News::class => [
       'tableName' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
   ],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you created a `EXT:myext/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php` with

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
return [
    \M3\MyExt\Domain\Model\FileReference::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_news',
        'properties' => [
            //'originalFileIdentifier' => [
            //    'fieldName' => 'uid_local'
            //]
        ]
    ],
];
```

Comment: it works with `'tableName' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',`

Answer (score 1):

I try this:

```
 /**
 * @var NewsRepository|null
 */
private ?NewsRepository $newsRepository = null;

/**
 * @param NewsRepository $newsRepository
 * @return void
 */
public function injectNewsRepository(NewsRepository $newsRepository)
{
    $this->newsRepository = $newsRepository;
}
```

with the result

```
Call to a member function getMyNews() on null
```

---

this:

```
public function __construct(NewsRepository $newsRepository)
{
    $this->dependency = $newsRepository;
}
```

with the result

```
Too few arguments to function M3\MyExt\Controller\MyController::__construct(), 0 passed in /.../TYPO3/typo3-10LTS-latest/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 3480 and exactly 1 expected
```

---

and this:

```
$newsRepository = $this->objectManager->get(\M3\Wihemer\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository::class);
```

with the result

```
database.tx_myext_domain_model_news' doesn't exist
```

---

I find no way to use my extended NewsRepository ...
It all looks like error in Dependency Injection, but where?

I have no problem to use the original NewsRepository, but not my own ...